# jQuery return gridview method

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        // note: the `Delete` is case sensitive and is the title of the button
        var DeleteButtons = jQuery('#<%= gvShoppingCart.ClientID %> :button[value=Delete]');
       DeleteButtons.each(function () {
           var onclick = jQuery(this).attr('onclick');
           jQuery(this).attr('onclick', null).click(function () {
               if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete item from shopping cart?")) {
                   return onclick();
               }
               else {
                   return false;
               }
           });
       });
   });
</script>
```

How can I change the above code to return the method below if true (instead of onclick())

```
 protected void gvShoppingCart_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        //code here
    }
```

EDIT: new code below -

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(document).ready(function () {
         $('.deleteStyle').click(function () {
             return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete");
         });
     });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .deleteStyle
    {
    }
</style>
```

Gridview Delete:

```
<asp:CommandField ControlStyle-CssClass="deleteStyle" ShowDeleteButton="True" ButtonType="Button"   />
```

gvRoles_RowDeleting (Note I am testing it out on Roles Gridview Now!)

```
protected void gvRoles_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        BusinessLayer.Roles rls = new BusinessLayer.Roles();
        rls.deleteRole(rls.getRole(gvRoles.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString()));
        this.BindRoles();
    }
```

Comment: why not use the row command method?

Comment: It's not working because of this line `ButtonType="Button"`

Comment: Thanks it works now!!!!!! so that code won't work on a button? :/

Comment: Nope that code will only work for links I've modified my answer below and included an example for button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're determined to use jQuery here's a simple example:

### Example 1:

Please note for this example you should remove `ButtonType="Button"` from the CommandField

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            $('.deleteStyle').click(function () {
                return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete item from shopping cart?");
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .deleteStyle
        {
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvShoppingCart" runat="server" OnRowDeleting="gvShoppingCart_RowDeleting">
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ControlStyle-CssClass="deleteStyle" DeleteText="Delete" ShowDeleteButton="true" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

### Example 2:

This example shows you how achieve the same functionality using `ButtonType="Button"`:

Just change the grid view id's to the required value;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('#<%= gvShoppingCart.ClientID %> :button[value=Delete]').each(function () {
            var onclick = jQuery(this).attr('onclick');
            jQuery(this).attr('onclick', null).click(function () {
                var gridViewName = "gvShoppingCart";
                if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete item from shopping cart?")) {
                    var deleteItem = onclick.replace("javascript:__doPostBack('gvShoppingCart','", "");
                    deleteItem = deleteItem.replace("')", "");
                    __doPostBack('gvShoppingCart', deleteItem);
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ButtonType="Button" />
```

Comment: Yes I must specifically use jQuery!

Comment: Thanks for the update however both ok and cancel will delete item.

Comment: In your question you said you only want the method to run if it returns true?If you remove `return` it will run for both Ok and Cancel.Please mark as answered if my answer helped you

Comment: if ok is pressed I would like it to call the gvShoppingCart_RowDeleting method shown above to delete the item from shopping 
and if cancel is pressed I would like it to do nothing.

Comment: So use the answer I've provided.It does exactly what you've described

Comment: What exactly is happening?Please note if you only want the RowDeleting to fire if a user clicks Ok you MUST have the `return` in the jQuery click function.

Comment: As I said i have copied you simple Jqeury example and tested it out it works but when I click cancel item is still being deleted. How can I fix that?

Comment: That's not supposed to happen,you're doing something wrong.Please edit your question and post the new code I'd like to have a look at it